# Push down values without shifting the row

Tags: vba, excel

So have this button on a form and I cant make the data on 3 cells (Ex:C1,D1,E1) go down 1 Row without shifting the whole sheet.

[image: Table Example]

How do i make the values go down after being inserted so that i can leave Row1 allways open for new values?

This is the code on the command button, can i embed the solution on it or do I have to do it somewhere else?

```
 Private Sub CommandButtonAddDes_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Activate sheet
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C:C")) + 1

'Transfer info
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Des
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = ComboBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TextBox1.Value


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try doing what you need while recording a macro and checking generated code?

Comment: Are you just trying to get those 3 columns to move down? So you want to enter the data then have everything move down one row so that row `A1:E1` is empty again?

Comment: @EganWolf I did but how do i keep pushing down instead of rewriting the data on the cells below?

Comment: From the image you provided it's impossible to realise which one is the first row. Also the code you provided doesn't put values into first row. Please be more specific.

Comment: @Mike I just want to cut the values that are inserted and move them down 1 row without overwriting them because in the end I want to make a sum of the values that have been added that day. ( Have the rest figured out i just cant see out do I keep listing the values from top to bottom without overwriting).

Comment: Check my answer below. It will push all values down on a row in columns `C:E`. You may need to adjust which columns are being pushed down and from which row it starts.

Comment: This looks like a job for a table/`ListObject`...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to make sure that the cells being updated are then moved down automatically. You can do that with a change event on the sheet code behind like this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Checks if the column being changed is C - E
    If Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 5 Then
        'Checks if the row being changed is row 2
        If Target.Row = 2 Then
            'Inserts a new row and pushes what is in C2:E2 down one row
            Range("C2:E2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This code will go in the sheets code behind. So, you will have to right-click on the sheet that you have this data on and then click on view code (or just double-click the sheet)

Putting the code there will tell Excel to watch that sheet for changes and then the code checks if it is happening to one of those 3 cells (`C2:E2`)

Comment: "Looks like you want to make sure that the cells being updated are then moved down automatically."
Exacly! But im not sure where do you want me to add this code...

Comment: Right click on the tab of the Sheet you are using and select View Code, then paste the code there...

Answer (score 0):

With data in **C1**, **D1** and **E1** just:

```
Range("C1:E1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

This pushes down the three cells rather than the entire row.

**EDIT#1:**

Put this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Long
    c = Target.Column
    If c = 3 Or c = 4 Or c = 5 Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C1:E1")) = 3 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("C1:E1").Insert shift:=xlDown
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Once you have entered all 3 values in **C1** through **E1**, the values will get pushed down automatically.

Comment: But how do I make the new data appear from NewData(C1) to OldData(C2)?

Comment: @JonhDoe  Not sure I understand.... **first** enter a value in `C1` **second** enter a value in `D1`  **third** enter a value in `E1` **fourth** run the macro

Comment: I just want to make sure that the cells being updated are then moved down automatically with the new values allways staying on top!

Comment: @JonhDoe  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: The values are entered in C2:E2, C1:E1 is the "last logs" header. The code you wrote pushes C2:E2 down to C3:E3 and then it keeps replacing C3:E3 with the new values, also it takes the fomat(fill color, etc.) from C1:E1 and sets them on C2:E2.

Comment: @JonhDoe  In your post, you said: *"make the data on 3 cells (Ex:C1,D1,E1) go down 1 Row*"  so that is what my cde does!

Comment: Yes but it glitches out with the fomat and it skips some value inserts.
https://imgur.com/ucTRrnO

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**: changed lat column index from "D" to "E" and starting row index from "3" to "2"

Maybe you’re after this

```
Private Sub CommandButtonAddDes_Click()
    With Sheet1
        With .Range("C2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
            .Offset(1).Value = .Value
            .Resize(1) = Array(Des, ComboBox.Value, TextBox1.Value)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Should different rows need to be "inserted" you just change the row index.

Comment: Im getting a "list separator error" after `With .Range(“C3:D”)`

Comment: Try using proper quotation marks. I’m writing from a mobile phone so maybe mine are not the right ones

Comment: @JohnDoe, did you get it working with edited quotation marks?

Comment: @JohnDoe, any chance for my attempt at helping you to to get a feedback ?

Comment: Yes @DisplayName sorry about that I trying some other lines, its has this weird behavior where its duplicating the "Des"  and "ComboBox.Value" but on the dupe theres not value on "TextBox1.Value". I almost got it with " Range("C2:E2").Insert Shift:=xlDown " but it has the bug I stated on the comment of Garys Student awnser!

Comment: I don’t understand what’s the weird behaviour: is it some duplication or the absence of value on textbox1.value? And what’s this latter? Maybe you can add some example of a desired behaviour with some “before” and “after” scenarios

Comment: @JohnDoe, now I could test it and found out what you were referring: see edited code and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code on your userform. Ensure your input box names are correct, i.e. ComboBox1, TextBox1, etc. I don't understand what "Des" is. If you need it in row 2 then just change the 1s to 2s.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C1:E1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .Range("C1").Value = Des.Value
    .Range("D1").Value = ComboBox.Value
    .Range("E1").Value = TextBox1.Value
End With
```

End Sub